# Using HttpClient with the RightScale API

Tags: wcf, rest, powershell, cloud-hosting, rightscale

I'm trying to use the WCF Rest Starter Kit with the [RightScale's Login API](http://support.rightscale.com/15-References/RightScale_API_Reference_Guide/01-Login_API) which seems fairly simple to use.

Edit - Here's a blog [entry](http://deengus.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!536FA5F72B74278!164.entry) I wrote on using Powershell to consume the API.

Edit - Created a generic .NET wrapper for the RightScale API - [NRightAPI](http://wiki.github.com/writeameer/NRightAPI/)

It's exactly as simple as it looks while using CURL. In order for me to obtain a login cookie all I need to do is:

> curl -v -c rightcookie -u username:password "https://my.rightscale.com/api/acct/accountid/login?api_version=1.0"

And I receive the following cookie:

> HTTP/1.1 204 No Content Date: Fri, 25  
>   Dec 2009 12:29:24 GMT Server: Mongrel 
>   1.1.3 Status: 204 No Content X-Runtime: 0.06121 
>  Content-Type: 
>   text/html; charset=utf-8 
>   Content-Length: 0 
>  Cache-Control: 
>   no-cache 
>  Added cookie 
>   _session_id="488a8d9493579b9473fbcfb94b3a7b8e5e3" for domain my.rightscale.com, path /, 
>   expire 0 
>  Set-Cookie: 
>   _session_id=488a8d9493579b9473fbcfb94b3a7b8e5e3; 
>   path=/; secure Vary: Accept-Encoding

However, when I use the following C# code:

> HttpClient http = new
>   HttpClient("https://my.rightscale.com/api/accountid/login?api_version=1.0"); 
>   http.TransportSettings.UseDefaultCredentials
>   = false; 
>  http.TransportSettings.MaximumAutomaticRedirections
>   = 0; 
>  http.TransportSettings.Credentials =
>   new NetworkCredential("username",
>   "password"); 
>   Console.WriteLine(http.Get().Content.ReadAsString());

Instead of a HTTP 204, I get a redirect:

> You are being <a>
>   href="https://my.rightscale.com/dashboard">redirected <a>

How do I get the WCF REST starter kit working with the RighScale API ?

Answer (score 6):

I needed to add a "Authorization: Basic " header to my request.

In additional to the initial code I had posted:

> HttpClient http = new HttpClient("https://my.rightscale.com/api/acct/accountid/login?api_version=1.0"); 
>   http.TransportSettings.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
>  http.TransportSettings.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 0; 
>  http.TransportSettings.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

I need to add the Authorization header along with the REST request with the username/password as follows:

> byte[] authbytes =
>   Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Concat("username",":", "password")); 
>   string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(authbytes); 
>   string authorization = string.Concat("Authorization: Basic ", base64); 
>   http.DefaultHeaders.Add(authorization);

And then when I made the request:

> Console.WriteLine(http.Get().Content.ReadAsString());

I received the HTTP 204 along with the session cookie I was looking for. What can I say, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is awesome :) !

Comment: Here is a shortcut http.DefaultHeaders.Authorization = Credential.CreateBasic("user", "password");

Comment: Thanks very much Darrel, that was very useful.  I could have voted that up if it was a separate answer.

Comment: No problem.  I'm in the process of writing a few posts on the Microsoft.Http library.  You may find some other useful stuff there. http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2009/12/08/why-the-microsoft-http-library-is-awesome/

Comment: Using Powershell with RightScale’s API
http://deengus.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!536FA5F72B74278!164.entry

Comment: Here is an example using NRightAPI:

http://github.com/writeameer/NRightAPI/tree/master/Downloads/